# sort or shuffle list during pug iteration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am trying to perform array operations such as concat, shuffle,  and sort during pug iteration.

from [pug](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html) documentation, this is possible:

```
ul
  each val in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    li= val
```

But what about something like:

```
ul
  each val in sort(list_obj1 + list_obj2) // i would also like to shuffle a list here...
    li= val
```

In my case, `list_obj1` and `list_obj2` are sent from a node js server. I know I can compute the sorted concatenated list on the server side. But for various implementation reasons I need it to be computed client-side.

How can I accomplish this?
Also, Is it possible use `underscore` for the array operations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can mix pug with JS, so nothing is impossible:

```
- var list = [1,2,3,4,5]
- list.sort((a,b)=>{return Math.random()-0.5})
each val in list
  div= val
```

[pen](https://codepen.io/mackie_pl/pen/GmYWEp)

Comment: A follow-up question: my ul element has a "refresh" button, I want the order to be randomized everytime I hit refresh, is there a way to call the js code inside pug for an event eg when a button is clicked?

Comment: No, if some pug randomization/sorting are mandatory in some project, one could choose to draw X random numbers for each element, and then loop client-side through previous randomizations - but I believe this would be barely usable. Normally, pug is inaccessible after the website is accessed by a browser, so new randomizations should be rewritten in website's JS.